# OpenNLP parser training

Tags: java, model, nlp, opennlp

I've tried asking this before on the OpenNLP sourceforge page, but it is still sadly languishing in the Help forums:

I have a treebank and I would like to train a model based on it. There was some code lying around using ParserME but that class doesn't seem to exist anymore. It looks like its been possibly replaced by TreebankParser but I can't seem to find any train tools in there. Is there a way of doing this?

Any hints welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got a reply back from the OpenNLP developers, they have updated the documentation to include parser training, I'll include it here in case anyone else has a similar problem:

https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/opennlp/index.php?title=Parser#Training_Tool